# Constant time range sum query

Tags: data-structures, time-series-analysis

I need to come up with a data structure that supports the following interface:

- new(time_stamp x, value v): insert a new data v for time stamp x
- update(time_stamp x, value v): update the data for time stamp x to v
- delete(time_stamp x): delete the data for time stamp x
- query(time_stamp x): returns sum of all data whose time stamp is less than or equal to x

The data structure needs to support out of sequence data. I need the query operation to run in O(1) time. While there is no restriction for other provided interfaces, I don't want to end up with O(n) time complexity for any of them.

An AVL tree seems a good candidate, however I'm not aware of any technique (maybe amortized cost analysis) to reduce the O(log n) query complexity for AVL tree to O(1).

I appreciate any suggestion or direction toward implementing such a data structure.

Comment: Seems like it requires some sort of persistence/retroactive data structure?

Comment: @D.W. Thanks for your edits. I have no guarantee that all these requirements are achievable or not. The following paper *LOGARITHMIC LOWER BOUNDS IN THE CELL-PROBE MODEL∗, suggests the new lower bound of  Ω(log n) for dynamic trees. This is a simplified version of an order handler, which query operation is the most time-sensitive operation.

Comment: @bearaqua Sorry for that, I meant AVL tree. I updated the question.

Comment: @AlirezaMajidi it seems more impossible to achieve constant-time queries using AVL trees because it seems like you want some sort of persistence (see D.W.'s comment), which only adds to the cost of maintenance. I also don't see directly how you would augment AVL trees for range sum query. Also, how are dynamic trees relevant to your question?

Comment: I doubt that your requirements are achievable, but I don't have a proof of that.  It is not hard to achieve $O(\log n)$ running time for all four operations (e.g., AVL trees suffice, as you hint, if you augment each node with a sum of all values below it), but I don't see how to achieve $O(1)$-time query if you want all other operations to take $o(n)$ time.

Comment: Van Emde Boas tree has better complexity on all the operations(O(log log n)). Still not possible to achieve O(1) time complexity.

Comment: I assume $n$ is the number of calls to new; is that right? And in your application, do you expect the range of the timestamps to be smaller than $n$, or larger?

Answer (score 1):

If the timestamps can take $T$ different values, then it is simple to implement the new, update, and delete operations in time $\Theta(T)$ and the query in time $O(1)$, by maintaining two arrays $val[ ]$ and $q[]$ of size $T$. The array $q[]$ is initially filled with zero values.

- new(x, v): set $val[x] = v$ and increment each $q[y]$ with $y\ge x$ by $v$;
- update(x, v): let $v' = val[x]$; increment each $q[y]$ with $y \ge x$ by $v-v'$, then set $val[x]=v$;
- delete(x, v): let $v' = val[x]$; decrement each $q[y]$ with $y \ge x$ by $v'$;
- query(x): return $q[x]$.

Note that $n$ (number of data items, that is, the number of total calls to new) is unrelated to $T$ (range of the timestamps). Whenever $T=o(n)$, the above implementation satisfies your requirements. For example, if a timestamp is a day of the year, $T$ will be a constant, even though $n$ can be arbitrarily large (because you can have arbitrarily many new and deletes).

If, on the other hand, $T$ can be larger than $n$, then as D.W. noted in his comment your requirements may be too strict.